# ruby Kernel: method behaves as instance method

Tags: ruby, module, kernel

```
class C
  def aaa
     print "aaa"
  end
end

C.new.aaa
# => "aaa"
```

now works method print from module Kernel

```
Kernel.methods.grep /^print/
# => [:printf, :print]
```

this means, that this method defines as class method.

Kernel doesn't have instance method print

```
Kernel.instance_methods.grep /^print/
# => []
```

So the first question is: How could it be, that class method calls from the object receiver? (C.new)

---

Also I tried do the same trick with own Module:

```
module M
  def self.print
    "111"
  end
end

class C
include M
  def aaa
     print 
  end
end

C.new.aaa
# => nil
```

You see, again it is Kernel module

but hierarchy tree is:

```
C.ancestors
# => [C, M, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]

M.methods.grep /^print/
# => [:print]
```

method defined as in Kernel. I can override only as instance method

```
module M
  def print
    "111"
  end
end


M.instance_methods.grep /^print/
# => [:print]
```

so how Kernel do this? how Kernel puts class method as instance method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
1.9.3-p327 :002 > Kernel.private_instance_methods.grep /^print/
=> [:printf, :print]
```

`instance_methods` only gives you a list of *public* instance methods. Since `Kernel` is included by `Object`, its private instance methods are *always* available, so there's no need to make them public.

Comment: oh, the big Thank You! I didn't know, that private methods don't show with instance_methods.